# How do I read this "install Script"? SpotifyController

Tags: installation, scripts, spotify

[Spotify Controller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cewan.spotify&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5jZXdhbi5zcG90aWZ5Il0).
I downloaded the files from the Ubuntu link provided in the aforementioned. Within was an instillation file with instructions, but i have no idea how to read it! Yes, I'm a complete  newbie. Thanks for the help in advance! 
This is what the "install" file contains ....

```
#!/bin/bash

echo
echo
echo Installing Spotify Controller Server...
sleep 1
echo
echo This installation file has been created for Ubuntu. If you are not using that distribution, installation might not work, but it should be pretty straightforward to modify the script to work for your distribution.
echo This program requires Spotify and Java. Press enter to continue...
read inputline
echo

echo Proceeding with installation. Creating application shortcut...
sleep 1
echo "/usr/bin/KillSpotifyController -silent" > SpotifyController
echo "echo Starting Spotify Controller..." >> SpotifyController
echo "cd '$PWD'" >> SpotifyController
echo "sh SpotifyController.sh" >> SpotifyController
chmod +x SpotifyController
sudo mv SpotifyController /usr/bin/
sudo cp -f resources/KillSpotifyController /usr/bin/
sudo cp -f resources/icon.png /usr/share/pixmaps/spotifycontroller.png
sudo cp -f resources/icon_stop.png /usr/share/pixmaps/spotifycontroller_stop.png

cp -f resources/SpotifyController.desktop $HOME/Desktop/
sudo cp -f resources/SpotifyController.desktop /usr/share/applications/

echo
echo Program is now installed. Simply run \"Spotify Controller\" from your desktop, or type \"SpotifyController\" to start the server. Make sure you have Spotify up and running with songs in the play queue.
sleep 1
echo
echo "To automatically start Spotify Controller Server when computer boots, add the application to System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications".
sleep 1
echo 
echo "Don't forget to install the Spotify Controller app from Play Store."
sleep 1
echo
echo If you experience any problems, see the file \"TROUBLESHOOTING\".
sleep 1
echo
echo "Happy Listening!"
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's go the way that I think it was meant to be used:

Open a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), and type this in:

```
cd PATH/TO/SPOTIFY # Edit PATH/TO/SPOTIFY to the path that spotify was extracted
bash ./install
```

It should work fine.

---

But if you want to read the script itself, here's a quick tutorial, or rather, a lot of bullets about it :P (based on the script you showed):

- Lines starting with `#` are (usually) comments. Also, usually, when you see `#` in the middle of the line, the rest of the line will be considered a comment. What's a comment? It's stuff that doesn't get executed (very useful for indicating what is going on, in a human-friendly way, hence the name "comment").
- Lines starting with `echo` print text. For example:

  ```
  echo testing 1 2 3
  ```

  will print:

  ```
  testing 1 2 3
  ```
- When you see a line like this:

  ```
  echo "testing 1 2 3" > FILE
  ```

  what will happen is that `testing 1 2 3` will be written to `FILE`. Notice that if `FILE` does not exist, it will be created, and if `FILE` has contents in it, it will be overridden. That's why sometimes you see this instead:

  ```
  echo "testing 1 2 3" >> FILE
  ```

  Which will then *append* `testing 1 2 3` to `FILE` (due to `>>` instead of `>`)
- When you see `sleep` at the beginning of a line, it will make the computer pause for `n` seconds, with `n` being the number after `sleep` (e.g. `sleep 1` will wait for one second)
- `read` will get input from you (you will enter text, and then when you press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, it will get sent to the program). How does the program read this? With the argument next to it. So `read test` will ask you to enter text, and once you're done, it will set the value of the variable `test` to the text you entered.
- To access a variable, prepend `$` to the name of the variable. BASH will automatically replace the variable with its contents. Check this example out:

  ```
   test="hello world"
   echo $test # Will show hello world
              # BASH will interpret this as:
              # echo "hello world"
  ```
- To assign a value to a variable, write a command in this format: `variable=value`. Notice that there are no spaces between `=`, `variable`, and `value`.
- `chmod` changes the access rights of a file. I won't go into detail about this (though there are some tutorials about this:  http://www.analysisandsolutions.com/code/chmod.htm, http://catcode.com/teachmod/, and http://www.perlfect.com/articles/chmod.shtml), but in the example you mentioned, it shows:

  ```
  chmod +x SpotifyController
  ```

  That will add execute permissions to `SpotifyController`, meaning that you can run it as an application
- `sudo` allows you to run commands as root (think administrator, if you're used to windows). Notice that it (usually) needs your password to run (for security reasons), but don't be alarmed if it doesn't ask each time. Most of the time, after entering your password once, it will wait for 15 minutes before asking for your password again (but, of course, it will only ask if you run `sudo` after the 15 minutes)
- `mv` moves a file from one place to another. If it stays in the same place, but you change the name of the new file, it acts as a renaming tool
- `cp` copies a file from one place to another. The `-f` switch forces it to, and `-r` copies it recursively (needed if you're copying a directory)
- `PWD` is a special variable that holds the current working directory (which can be set by `cd`)
- If you're wondering about the `\"`'s, you can check out BASH escaping tutorials: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/escapingsection.html, http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_03.html.

And, of course, if you want to learn more about BASH, check out these tutorials (but feel free to google around also, of course =):

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/
http://www.hypexr.org/bash_tutorial.php (less about scripting, and more about how to use the shell)
http://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial

Hope this helps!